# Is there a way to programmatically enable a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

```php
<?php

namespace wpplugin\basic;

class Basic extends \hg\wordpress\AbstractPlugin
{

    public function register()
    {

        add_action('wp_ajax_simple_ajax2', array($this, 'onBasicFunc'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_simple_ajax2', array($this, 'onBasicFunc'));

    }

    public function onBasicFunc()
    {
        $data = $_REQUEST; // retrieve your submitted data

        wp_send_json($_REQUEST); // return the processed data to the browser as json

        die();
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work when I try to call it from the frontend, but if I put the content inside functions.php it works as expected. I am guessing it's because I didn't enable the plugin, but is there a way to programatically enable it? My plugin is just supposed to be something that returns a result when doing an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's

- [activate_plugin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/) defined in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php (which isn't normally loaded from non-admin code, and note that obviously a PHP plugin file can't activate itself)
- wp-cli [wp plugin activate](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/activate/) if you meant activate from the command line without using the admin site
- (and at a pinch you could edit the active_plugins value in wp_options in the database, although note that it's a PHP serialized value and probably safest edited by unserializing the string in PHP, modifying and reserializing)

You'll probably need to add a [plugin header comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/) to your file to use one of these.

However the simplest way to get a script running is to drop it into wp-content/mu-plugins, the [must use plugins folder](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/), which you may have to create yourself first. (This is fairly powerful, so if you do have to create this it might be a good idea to not leave it writeable by the web server user.)

Comment: +1 for `mu-plugins` - if you want to have a plugin that requires no interaction whatsoever to activate, that's the best way to do it.

Comment: While this correctly describes how to activate a plugin programatically, this was not actually OP's issue. OP's issue was trying to hook AJAX callbacks from the front end, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not that you didn't enable the plugin, it's that you loaded code only on front end requests that needs to be loaded on back end requests.

When you add these hooks:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_simple_ajax2', array($this, 'onBasicFunc'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_simple_ajax2', array($this, 'onBasicFunc'));
```

You are adding callback functions to run when `admin-ajax.php` is called with the right arguments. The problem is that front end templates and code doesn't run on `admin-ajax.php`, which means that your callback function is not hooked to run.

Comment: Could you clarify? I am not sure I understand. Any example? I am calling admin-ajax.php when I call my hooks on the frontend and it works when I declare them inside functions.php.

Comment: Because functions.php is loaded in admin-ajax.php.